# Insert only stores the first digit, remainder are ignored

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a question regarding my database. I have develop a system where it will calculate the percentage automatically when user insert the values. My problem right now is, my database only stored the first digit. For example, if I enter 4000, it will only store 4,and at first I thought maybe there was something going on with the 3 zeroes behind but that was not it, and if I insert 3245, it still only store 3.

Below is my database;
[image]

and here the codes related to this database.

add records:

```html
<form action="" method="post">

<div>

<?php if ($id != '') { ?>

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

<p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>

<?php } ?>





<p><strong>Tarikh&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: *</strong>

<input type="text"  style="text-transform:uppercase" name="date" value=" <?php echo $date; ?>"/><br/></p>

<p><strong>Di bawah 60 Minit  : *</strong> <input type="text" name="casesolved_u"

value="<?php echo $casesolved_u; ?>"/><br/></p>

<p><strong>Jumlah kes &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: *</strong> <input type="text" name="casesolved_a"

value="<?php echo $casesolved_a; ?>"/></p>



<!--Remove Percentage entry -->


<p>* required</p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</div>

</form></center>



</body>

</html>



<?php }



/*

EDIT RECORD

*/

// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record

if (isset($_GET['id']))

{

// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{

// make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid

if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))

{

// get variables from the URL/form

$id = $_POST['id'];

$date = strtoupper($_POST['date']);

$casesolved_u = htmlentities($_POST['casesolved_u'], ENT_QUOTES);

$casesolved_a = htmlentities($_POST['casesolved_a'], ENT_QUOTES);



//check if empty

if ($date == '' || $casesolved_u == ''||$casesolved_a =='')

{

// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form

$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

renderForm($date, $casesolved_u, $casesolved_a, $percentage ,$error, $id);

}

else

{

 $percentage = ($casesolved_u * 100 / $casesolved_a);

 //apply the proper formatting

$casesolved_u = number_format ($casesolved_u, 2);
$casesolved_a = number_format ($casesolved_a, 2);
$percentage = number_format ($percentage,2);
 


// if everything is fine, update the record in the database

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ae SET date = ?, casesolved_u = ?, casesolved_a=?, percentage=?

WHERE id=?"))

{

$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $date, $casesolved_u, $casesolved_a, $percentage ,$id);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

}

// show an error message if the query has an error

else

{

echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";

}



// redirect the user once the form is updated

header("Location: view.php");

}

}

// if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message

else

{

echo "Error!";

}

}

// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form

else

{

// make sure the 'id' value is valid

if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)

{

// get 'id' from URL

$id = $_GET['id'];



// get the recod from the database

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, date, casesolved_u, casesolved_a, percentage FROM ae WHERE id =?"))



{

$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

$stmt->execute();



$stmt->bind_result($id, $date, $casesolved_u, $casesolved_a, $percentage);

$stmt->fetch();



// show the form

renderForm($date, $casesolved_u, $casesolved_a , $percentage, NULL, $id);



$stmt->close();

}

// show an error if the query has an error

else

{

echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement"; 

}

}

// if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page

else

{

header("Location: view.php");

}

}

}




/*

NEW RECORD

*/

// if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record

else

{

// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{

// get the form data

$date = strtoupper($_POST['date']);

$casesolved_u = htmlentities($_POST['casesolved_u'], ENT_QUOTES);

$casesolved_a = htmlentities($_POST['casesolved_a'], ENT_QUOTES);



// check that no empty value inserted

if ($date == '' || $casesolved_u == '' ||$casesolved_a == '')

{

// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form

$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

renderForm($date, $casesolved_u, $casesolved_a, $percentage, $error);

}

else

{


 $percentage = ($casesolved_u * 100 / $casesolved_a);

 //apply the proper formatting

$casesolved_u = number_format ($casesolved_u, 2);
$casesolved_a = number_format ($casesolved_a, 2);
$percentage = number_format ($percentage,2);


// insert the new record into the database

if ($stmt= $mysqli->prepare ("INSERT INTO ae (date, casesolved_u, casesolved_a, percentage) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"))

{

$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$date, $casesolved_u, $casesolved_a, $percentage);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

}

// show an error if the query has an error

else

{
echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";

}

// redirec the user

header("Location: view.php");

}

}

// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form

else

{

renderForm();

}

}

// close the mysqli connection

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

and here is the view code;

```html
<?php
// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');

// get the records from the database
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ae ORDER BY id"))
{
// display records if there are records to display
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
// display records in a table
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

// set table headers
echo "<tr><th>&nbsp Tarikh &nbsp</th><th> &nbsp Discaj Dalam Masa 2 Jam &nbsp </th><th> &nbsp Jumlah Kes &nbsp </th><th>Peratusan</th><th>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</th><th>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
// set up a row for each record
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>" . $row->date . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->casesolved_u . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->casesolved_a . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->percentage . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='records.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
}
// if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
else
{
echo "Tiada maklumat untuk dipamerkan";
}
}
// show an error if there is an issue with the database query
else
{
echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}

// close database connection
$mysqli->close();

?>
<p>
</p>
 <center><a href="records.php">  Tambah Rekod Baru</a></center>
</div>
```

Please, point me to where I do wrong that cause my database to only store the first digit into the database.

Comment: Note: Use `htmlentities` **only** for when you're displaying the result in HTML. Don't use it when encoding things for your database, you'll end up with things double encoded. Since you're using prepared statements you're protected from SQL injection bugs, so you don't need to over-do it.

Comment: I see...I'll fix that

Comment: You will want to escape properly when displaying this content, so test with input like `<strong>&copy;</strong>` to see how it shows up. It should show up as plain text. If you forget to escape when displaying you'll see **©** and if you over-escape it you'll see `&lt;strong&gt;&amp;copy;&lt;/strong&gt;`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation, already apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number_format` puts commas in as thousands separators. That is going to mess up any insert into MySQL (or most other databases) if the number is > 1,000 - such as 4,000 or 3,245. `number_format` is needed for people to easily read information, but not for the database.

Comment: So, what should I do to repair this?

Comment: @WanHazyan - Start by replacing all calls to number_format($x,2) with round($x,2)